# How to simulate multi interface wireless node and changing channels by Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

How to simulate an adhoc network with the following conditions in Omnet++ in IEEE802.11b/g? (omnetpp.ini and NED file are expected)

```
1-Two wireless nodes (e.g. n1 and n2) having two interfaces with each other(e.g i1 and i2)
2-n1.i1 makes a link to communicate with n2.i1 and also n1.i2 makes a link with n2.i2, n1.i1 means interface i1 of node n1
3-channel 1 are allocated to link n1.i1 and n2.i1 in all simulation runtime
4-channel 2 are allocated to link n1.i2 and n2.i2 in the first second of simulation runtime, then channel 3 in the 2nd second, and so on until 10nd seconds, then repeat this circle.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was really desperate to get an answer to this question, is there no one to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `examples\adhoc\ieee80211` in INET. It contains simple network for testing the IEEE 802.11 in ad-hoc mode.

Comment: Thanks, I look at it, but it is very simple, I can't reach to what I need.